# Can I reuse nonce in Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, nonce, sign-in-with-apple

My understanding is nonce shouldn't be reuse, but when I use this hard code nonce (a), I can sign in successfully.

```
let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
request.nonce = "a"
```

Is there any specification for this nonce?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't re-use the nonce, this value should be unique to avoid replay attacks as mentioned in [Authenticate the User and Request Information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple)

> **nonce**
>   A String value used to associate a client session and an ID
>   token. This value is used to mitigate replay attacks and is present
>   only if passed during the authorization request.

Check more about [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) and [nonces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)

Comment: When you mentioned replay attacks, do you mean attack to Apple's server?

Comment: @sarunw Yes, in the replay attack, the attacker will sniff your data and send to the server acting as you

Comment: why does it success in my case? I use duplicate nonce "a"